# Equal Risk Contribution portfolio scipy optimization not working

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, minimize

I'm trying to create a tool for an equal risk contribution portfolio,essentially following this article (https://quantdare.com/risk-parity-in-python/) but it is failing at the last step (def risk_parity_weights) as the scipy optimizer isn't working. It keeps giving me the initial weights as the optimized weights, and I know they aren't the optimized weights because even Excel Solver has been able to optimize this. All the others functions have been checked and are correct. Not sure what I'm doing wrong - please help!

```
#Calculate portfolio st.dev
    portfolio_stdev = np.sqrt(weights*covariances*weights.T)[0,0]

    #Calculate Marginal Risk Contribution of each asset
    MRC = covariances*weights.T/portfolio_stdev

    #Calculate Risk Contribution of each asset
    RC = np.multiply(MRC,weights.T)
    return RC

def risk_budget_objective_error(weights,*args):

    #Covariance table occupies the first position in args variable
    covariances = args[0]

    #State risk budgets
    assets_risk_budget = args[1]

    #Convert weights array to numpy matrix
    weights = np.matrix(weights)

    #Calculate portfolio st_dev
    portfolio_stdev = calculate_portfolio_stdev(ca_begweights,ca_cov)

    #Calculate risk contributions
    assets_risk_contribution = calculate_risk_contribution(ca_begweights,ca_cov)

    #Calculate desired risk contribution of each asset
    assets_risk_target = np.asmatrix(np.multiply(portfolio_stdev,assets_risk_budget))

    #Calculate error between desired contribution and calculated distribution of each asset
    error = sum(np.square(assets_risk_contribution - assets_risk_target.T))[0,0]

    return error

def risk_parity_weights(covariances,assets_risk_budget, initial_weights):

    #Constraints to optimization
    #sum equals 100%
    cons = ({'type':'eq','fun':lambda x: np.sum(x) - 1.0},
              {'type':'ineq','fun':lambda x: x})

    #Optimization in scipy
    optimize_result = minimize(risk_budget_objective_error,
                           x0 = initial_weights,
                           args = (covariances, assets_risk_budget),
                           method = 'SLSQP',
                           constraints = cons,
                           tol = Tolerance,
                           options = {'disp':True})

    #Get optimized weights
    weights = optimize_result.x

    return weights
```

`risk_parity_weights(ca_cov,risk_budget_all, ca_begweights)` gives me

```
Optimization terminated successfully.    (Exit mode 0)
            Current function value: 9.54000328523598e-07
            Iterations: 1
            Function evaluations: 5
            Gradient evaluations: 1
```

See variables data below

```
ca_cov = array([[ 5.28024463e-06, 3.29734889e-07, -7.04781216e-08], [ 3.29734889e-07, 1.32373854e-05, 3.71807979e-08], [-7.04781216e-08, 3.71807979e-08, 3.50845569e-05]]) 

risk_budget_all = Unnamed: 1 0.333333 Unnamed: 2 0.333333 Unnamed: 3 0.333333 Name: Risk Budget, dtype: object 

ca_begweights = array([0.33333333, 0.33333333, 0.33333333])
```

Comment: Did you try changing method?

Comment: @kurag no, which one would you suggest?

Comment: You can find info about some method here https://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/mathematical_optimization/